# ASP.NET Session State Security Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website in which people's 'logged in' state is confirmed by their session cookie (and a value within the session which they get after they log in). The cookie is set to httpOnly & require SSL.

Let's say somebody has 2 Firefox windows open, window (A) has my application and they are logged in, and window (B) has something else open.

If they close window (A) without explicitly logging out, then open a new window (C) and access a logged-in-only resource from my web application, it will still load because the cookie is *still* there and they are authenticated. The timeout on my sessions is already very low, but I need to stop this attack possibility because people may access their data on a public computer.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are you talking about new browser window or new tab in the same browser?

Comment: @Kamarey: A new browser window. If (A) is closed without logout and a new window (C) is opened, and I copy the URL from previous (A) into (C) then I can accessed the logged in contents again.

Comment: I know that the newest version of Firefox even keeps the same session after closing all windows. The next time you'll keep on working with the same session as before. Probably your cookie will be timed out already, since your timeout is very low.

Comment: @Joop: Just tested on FF 3.5 - I got a new session id in a new browser window.

Comment: @Kamarey: Good to know. It would be very annoying if not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about other browsers, but Firefox keeps the same session id among all browser windows. You should close ALL windows of Firefox to generate a new session id. So in your example close window A and B, then open C and you should be redirected to login page or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a simple approach of destroying the cookie on the window.close event.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have this functionality in that all windows can share the same session cookie for the same site. There is no way I know of server side to stop a browser from doing this.

If you absolutely need to stop this from happening then I can only suggest storing an additional value in the pages themselves or the querystring and also confirming this value within your session.

This could prove to be quite an overhaul of your security though.